# stop/kill sh script and reaload every N/A minutes

Tags: scripts, cron, slideshow

i am using feh automatic slideshow(source is samba network folder) all working fine,sometimes i add some pictures,sometimes i delete someth. but if is only one picture in folder,than slideshow is stopped and not run next pics,if i add to folder some pictures. I need some script for kill/stop feh.sh script and reload it every N/A minutes(with cron for example).Its possible?Or some different method?

Comment: Put `killall $(pgrep feh.sh) && /path/to/feh.sh &` in your crontab. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jos
LINUX:~$ killall $(pgrep feh.sh) && /home/blablabla/Plocha/feh.sh &

[1] 17930
LINUX:~$ 17925: žádný proces nenalezen(cant find any process)

screenshot
http://pasteboard.co/JHXhhS95C.png

Comment: That means there was no process `feh.sh` running at that time.

Comment: @Jos
http://pasteboard.co/JHXhhS95C.png ,its running in this moment..

Comment: Sorry, I have mixed up two ways of killing the running process. You can either `killall feh.sh` or `kill -9 $(pgrep feh.sh)`.

Comment: @Jos killall feh.sh not working `bohuslavd@PRON069-LINUX:~$ killall feh.sh (feh still running) bohuslavd@PRON069-LINUX:~$ killall feh.sh feh.sh: žádný proces nenalezen (no process found)` kill PID $(pgrep feh.sh) working,but PID from this script is always different,so useless

Comment: Look carefully. The command is `kill -9 $(pgrep feh.sh)`. The part `pgrep feh.sh` retrieves the PID, whatever it is. The `-9` is a flag that specifies the type of killing. See `man kill` and `man pgrep`.

Comment: @Jos
hi again, i can kill feh.sh but this script have 2 process
http://pasteboard.co/K4oTdvCJM.png

Answer (score 0):

just add pkill feh(without .sh) with some refresh to cron

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)